# How to Send email with High Importance in asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendmail

How do I set the code below to generate email with high priority in the subject line? Thank you for any guidance.

```
Private Sub SendEmail(ByVal pharmEmail As String, ByVal backupEmail As String)
    Dim smtpClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
    Dim message As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

    Try
        Dim fromAddress As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailFromAddr"), WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailFromName"))
        message.From = fromAddress
        message.To.Add(pharmEmail)
        message.Subject = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailSubject")
        If (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("backupEnabled") = True) Then
            message.CC.Add(backupEmail)
        End If
        message.IsBodyHtml = True
        Dim orderURL As New HyperLink
        orderURL.Text = "here"
        orderURL.NavigateUrl = "http://" & WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServerName") & "/User/ReviewOrder.aspx?orderID=" & webOrderID
        message.Body = "An order was created using the account of " + Profile.FirstName.ToString() + " " + Profile.LastName.ToString() + ". " + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailBody") + "<a href='" + orderURL.NavigateUrl + "'>here.</a>"
        'message.Body = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailBody") & " " & orderURL.
        smtpClient.Send(message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHandler.WriteError(ex.ToString)
        Throw ex
    End Try
```

Comment: Use the `Priority` property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692919/can-i-mark-an-email-as-high-importance-for-outlook-using-system-net-mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can set the `Priority` property on the `MailMessage`. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.priority(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: The first two option were returning an error saying that               `message.Priority = MailPriority.High` was obsolete but the following did work without any issue,                                                                           `message.Priority = Net.Mail.MailPriority.High.` Thank you for your guidance.