# Powershell Email: How to send email with High Importance?

Tags: email, powershell

I am trying to send an email with High Importance using `Powershell`. But when mail comes to inbox it does not mark with High Importance.

Following is email script:

```
$EmailFrom = "monitoring@mydomainname.no"
$EmailTo = "fatherazrael@tcs.com"
$Subject = "Disk Space Low: $server"

$Body = "Server Name:  $server, <NEED NEW LINE> Drive: C,  <NEED NEW LINE>  Total Size: $sizeGB,  <NEED NEW LINE> Space Left: $freeSpaceGB"

$SMTPServer = "scan.opinergo.fn"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25)
#$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("<From mail ID>", "Password");
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

For High Importance i have added following but none is working when mail comes to outlook:

1) `$EmailPriority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High`

Mail Comes but no importance

2) `$Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High`

Mail Comes but no importance

3) `$Priority = "high"`

Mail Comes but no importance

4) `$EmailPriority = "high"`

Mail Comes but no importance

Comment: how do you pass the `$EmailPriority` variable to the SMTPClient?

Comment: I never used powershell to send mails, but from skimming over the docs I guess you have to build a message using the [MailMessage class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the appropiate headers there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mark an Email as "High Importance" for Outlook using System.Net.Mail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692919/can-i-mark-an-email-as-high-importance-for-outlook-using-system-net-mail)

Comment: @Gerald Schneider: Simply just like other parameter shown in snippet

Answer (score 12):

This code would send out a high priority email:

```
  $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yourDomain.com") 
  $email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
  $email.From = "fromEmail@email.com"
  $email.To.Add("ToEmail@email.com")
  $email.Subject = "Enter  your Email Subject"
  $email.Body = "Enter the body of your email"
  $email.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
  $smtp.Send($email)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using the [`Send-MailMessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) cmdlet and specify the `-Priority` parameter:

```
$password = "pass" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object PSCredential("username", $password)

Send-MailMessage `
    -To recipient@example.com `
    -From sender@example.com `
    -Subject Example `
    -SmtpServer smtp.example.com `
    -Credential $credentials
    -Priority High
```

Answer (score 1):

## $emailMessage.Priority = 2

```
$emailSmtpServer = “xyz”
$emailSmtpServerPort = “587”
$emailSmtpUser = “x@y.z”
$emailSmtpPass = “abc”

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = “x@y.z”
$emailMessage.To.Add( “x1@y.z” )
$emailMessage.To.Add( “x2@y.z” )
$emailMessage.Subject = “EMAIL CHECK!”
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = “True”

#Low Priority
#$emailMessage.Priority = 1

#High Priority
$emailMessage.Priority = 2

$emailMessage.Body = @”
    Email body... <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Message Sent from Power Shell.
“@

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );

$SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage )
```